# Change column names in DT package right before output to Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to change the column names of a datable at the very last step before I output it in a Shiny app.  The display names are quite long, and I do not want to change them while I'm manipulating the datatable.  There are a lot more formatting changes to the datatable than below in my actual dataset.

Here is a dummy dataset:

```
library(DT)
test.df <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b = 21:20, c = 31:30, d = 31:40)
test.dt <- datatable(test.df) %>% formatPercentage('a', 0) %>% formatCurrency('c', '$')
```

Now, how would I change the column names to c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4')?  Again, I would like this to be the last step before I output the datatable with a `renderDataTable` function.

If there's a way to create column aliases as opposed to changing the actual column names, that would work as well.

Comment: Just use the `colnames` argument of `datatable`, which will create a display name like you wanted. Please refer to the documentation.

Comment: But test.df is already a datatable.  The documentation has colnames as an argument in the datatables function.  (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)  I don't see how to include the column names at the very end, after I've already converted the df into a datatable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use the `colnames` argument of `datatable`. This only changes the display name, so you can still use the original column names in your formatting code.

```
test.dt <- datatable(test.df, colnames=c("aa", "cc")) %>% formatPercentage('a', 0) %>% formatCurrency('c', '$')
```

Comment: Works beautifully, didn't realize colnames only changes the display of the columns, not the underlying names.

Comment: It seems the behaviors of format* function has been changed as of DT version 0.2 released on Aug 8, 2016. The provided example no longer works with v0.2. Now the format* functions expect the new names of the renamed columns. In other words, display names must be used to select columns in the format* functions.